# What is the legality behind landlords throwing away tenants belongings UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, landlord, tenant, tenancy-rules

Me and my housemates have started having issues with our landlords, where they will dispose of any utensils left on the kitchen worktop or in cupboards without being cleaned. Before moving into the house we all signed an agreement to the house rules. Here is an excerpt from the agreement:

> **"In the kitchen/lounge and all of the communal areas: there must be no dirty plates/cutlery/cooking utensils left lying around. Please ensure you do your washing up and put it away before cleaners visit. DO NOT put dirty plates in cupboard as they will be removed and disposed of. Please ensure you remove your personal belongings from the lounge and any washing drying on radiators or airers to allow the cleaner to clean and dust properly."**

When signing this agreement I thought nothing of it, that they were merely covering their own backs. However, now they have enforced these rules I am curious as to the legality of it.

By signing an agreement does it make it legal for landlords to take our stuff? Is this covered under the **"Torts (Interference with Goods) Act 1977"**

Thanks

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).